# Angular 2 Directive for a component overrides ng-content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, directive

I have a Component that is called ButtonComponent:

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'btn',
    template: '<div class="btn"><ng-content></ng-content></div>'
})
export class ButtonComponent { }
```

and Directive:

```
import { Directive, Input } from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: 'btn[dialog-data]'
})
export class DialogButtonDirective {
    @Input('dialog-data') 
    public dialogData: any;
}
```

But if I try to use it like this:

```
<btn [dialog-data]="dart()">DART</btn>
```

Then button have nothing inside of it.
Why? When I'm not using this directive everything's fine.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it's a bit confusing but I found the answer. This code isn't working because DialogButtonDirective declared in 'directives' field before ButtonComponent.

So I've changed this:

```
directives: [DialogButtonDirective, ButtonComponent]
```

To this:

```
directives: [ButtonComponent, DialogButtonDirective]
```

And it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect the original cause to be somewhere else (some caching of the browser or the server you're using) and this change caused a proper reload. This change is absolutely meaningless (as long as `DialogButtonDirective` and `ButtonComponent` are classes instead of arrays of providers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error via Plunker, but it actually takes place in my application. And it's not due caching or server (lite-server). I know, this may be insane, but my solution actually works.